# Unable to connect to Neo4j from c# driver Session to fabric database

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Using the Neo4j.Driver (4.1.0) I am unable to connect a session to server's configured fabric database.  It works fine in the Neo4j Browser.  Is there a trick to setting the context to a fabric database?

This times out:

`var session = driver.AsyncSession(o => o.WithDatabase("fabric"));`

Actual database names work fine.

Does the c# driver not support setting the Session context to a fabric database?

I'm trying to execute something like the following:

```
use fabric.graph(0)
match ...
set...
```

I found a workaround by co-opting a sub-query as follows, but it seems that setting the session context would make more sense.

```
use fabric
call {
  use fabric.graph(0)
  match ...
  set ...
  return 0
}
return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet worked with fabric. But I have worked with clusters. You can only add nodes/edges to the one Neo4j database that has a WRITE role. To do this you need a small function to query the routing table and determine the write database. Here's the key query:

```
CALL dbms.cluster.routing.getRoutingTable({}) YIELD ttl, servers UNWIND servers as server with server where server.role='WRITE' RETURN server.addresses
```

You then address your write query to that specific database.

Comment: If you're using the Drivers, you should use `bolt+routing://` (`1.7.2`) or `neo4j://` (`4+`) if you want to connect to a cluster - as that does the routing for you - you should only have to do the above if you are writing something custom, or using the REST endpoint

Comment: I was using v4 driver. I don't know what you mean by "sometng custom" but I was simply adding nodes and edges, typically with LOAD CSV. It doesn't work unless your driver is connected to the correct server.

Comment: You only need to know the server if you are running those queries via the browser, and at that point the easiest way to work out the server is with `:sysinfo` - if you're using the `neo4j://` schema with a cluster - and calling a write query (`.WriteTransaction()`) you shouldn't need to know that - as it handles the routing for you. Especially important in cases of failover. 'Something Custom' is just if you are trying to implement your _own_ routing strategy.

Comment: I run queries from an Azure VM with python code. I need to know the specific database before writing to it.

Comment: The point of `neo4j://` or `bolt+routing` is that you _don't_ need to know the _server_ - for all you would need to know your database. Python connecting to `neo4j://localhost:7474` for example will auto-route to the correct server provided you say it's a `write` query - see https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/client-applications/#python-driver-connection-uris